# Currency Field in a Power Automate to create an Opportunity in Dynamics CRM from a SharePoint List

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm creating a Power Automate flow that will create an opportunity in Dynamics CRM if certain conditions are met when a record is created in a SharePoint Online List, but the Create New Record block for Dynamics asks as mandatory the Currency field.

I have tried typing USD, US Dollar, Empty, etc., and none of them works. Tried different approaches to that field. Even created a new currency in Dynamics called DOL and its the same.

How could I fix this?

This is the error message I'm getting.

```
{
  "_transactioncurrencyid_value": "DOL",
  "_customerid_value": "A",
  "_customerid_type": "Bronze",
  "name": "Bakery",
  "budgetamount": 900,
  "_parentcontactid_value": "Saul",
  "description": "CCC",
  "_ownerid_value": "Stefano"
}

{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Invalid lookup_type value",
  "source": "dynamicscrmonline-eus2.azconn-eus2.p.azurewebsites.net",
  "debugInfo": "clientRequestId: f80d8df5-d57c-46f8-83a1-8b579352aa5b"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We call that lookup datatype (aka EntityReference) which is a foreign key of another entity (aka Database table). The expected value to be passed on that payload is GUID.

```
"_transactioncurrencyid_value":"9C72D8B6-AD23-E511-80F7-C4346BAC59AC",
```

You have to find out that Key GUID for that DOL or USD currency record. Same applies to `parentcontactid` and `ownerid`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I still have the same issue. here are the screenshots https://prnt.sc/p2czxt https://prnt.sc/p2d03y https://prnt.sc/p2d08g hope this helps.

Comment: @rzbartali it says error in query syntax. Start with a basic payload & make it work on a simple entity to learn first. Then add more attributes to that slowly.

Comment: Hi Arun, thats what im trying to do, im only using the mandatory fields, do you have any suggestions or resources where i could read about this? i havent been able to find anything useful

Comment: @rzbartali [check this link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/create-opportunity-in-Dynamics-based-on-email/m-p/46896/highlight/true#M4258). the value for _customerid_value should be GUID again.. make sure you have hard coded the value & MS Flow testing is done, then populate dynamics values.. if you want to create a record in CRM from SharePoint record values, then create it first & get the GUID & populate in Flow step